# How to add clearfix just inside a div

Tags: html, clearfix

I have an image and one div.I want "text2" to come under "text1" .WHen I add `clearfix` the "text2" come under image .

I know that I can use "`br`" but is possible to have same effects without"`<br>`"

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bSrPB/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bSrPB/1/

Comment: Occam's razor: just don't clear anything. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/bSrPB/4/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want text over image ?

if so you could use something position relative on div and position absolute on text, if text is still under image you can use z-index: 999 if you want to force text over image

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: left` to your child *div* element, like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/" style="float:left">
    <div style="float:left"> 
        <span>TEXT1</span>
          <div class="clear"></div> 
        <span>TEXT2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Online example](http://jsfiddle.net/bSrPB/3/)